# Avoid repeating columns in DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview

This is my DataTable:

```
ItemPartNumber        VendorName      Price
ANNF213               SAMSUNG         265.41
GDFF31D               HP              65.10
ANNF213               APPLE           115.51
FSF2122               MICROSOFT       655.47
GDSGG32               NOKIA           250.58
ANNF213               SAMSUNG         225.40
```

It has `ANNF213` three times. I want to take only the first one, and wish to omit the rest rows.

**Desired Output DataTable:**

```
ItemPartNumber        VendorName      Price
ANNF213               SAMSUNG         265.41
GDFF31D               HP              65.10
FSF2122               MICROSOFT       655.47
GDSGG32               NOKIA           250.58
```

So, my simple question is how to get the rows after omitting the repeating particular column values?

I've tried:

```
DataView view = new DataView(dataTable);
dataTable = view.ToTable(true, "ItemPartNumber", "VendorName", "Price");
//This isn't working.

dataTable = view.ToTable(true, "ItemPartNumber");
//This is working, but only `ItemPartNumber` is there on data table, but I need all three columns. Help me in this!
```

Comment: First according to row-number or a real order(f.e. keep highest price)?

Comment: I'm okay with both. I can understand your comment. I've been asked to omit duplicate rows that consists repeating part numbers, no conditions as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Linq-To-DataTable, if you just want to keep the first:

```
dataTable = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("ItemPartNumber"))
    .Select(grp => grp.First())
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

If you want something more meaningful, for example keep the row with the highest price:

```
dataTable = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("ItemPartNumber"))
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(row => row.Field<decimal>("Price")).First())
    .CopyToDataTable();
```